# Android: ImageSwitcher getImageId()

Tags: android

Have a question. I'm using image switcher, and this is the way how I set Image to switcher...

```
 imageSwitcher.setImageResource(some_image_id);
```

So the question is: How to get image id that is set to image switcher ? I cannot find method like `imageSwitcher.getImageId();` Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageSwitcher` is a derived class from [`ViewAnimator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html), so you can use:

```
android.widget.ViewAnimator#getDisplayedChild ()
```

to get the index of the currently displayed child view, or:

```
android.widget.ViewAnimator#getCurrentView ()
```

to get the View corresponding to the currently displayed child.

If you look at the [**source code**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.1_r1/android/widget/ImageView.java#ImageView.setImageResource%28int%29), setImageResource(int) adds an ImageView:

```
public void setImageResource(int resid)
{
    ImageView image = (ImageView)this.getNextView();
    image.setImageResource(resid);
    showNext();
}
```

Comment: I know about this method, but they didn't return to me image id...( I need image id to write switch...like switch (imageSwither.getImageId()) { case R.drawable.some image: break; } Something like this

Comment: You won't be able to get it, I'm afraid. Can't you use the index for the switch block? If not, I would keep a hashmap of the index and the resource ID.

Comment: ImageSwitcher does not store the resId, as you can see from the snippet above. This id is used by ImageView to retrieve the resource, using a private filed `mResource` and a private method `resolveUri()`. The only way I see it possible is to rewrite both ImageSwitcher and ImageView to make that field public (or add a getter). I suggest you to store the ids while you add them instead.

Comment: The reason why I want to use image id's is to write simple and understandable cases instead of integers 0,1,2,3,4...But it's ok, I can add constants...Thank's in any way...